# How display a ComboBoxItem in beginning and in the ending in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, windows-runtime

In my WinRT C#/XAML application I have a ComboBox where I'm binding to a `List<T>`. The binding is working like I want, but I would like to have an item that is placed on the beginning of the list called **`Choose Chore`** and one at the end called **`Add New`**. What I have above only displays the bound list:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="currentChore" 
          SelectedItem="Choose Chore" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Summary"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ChoreList, Mode=TwoWay}"  
          SelectedValue="{Binding ChoreSingle, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <ComboBoxItem Content="Choose Chore" Foreground="Black" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Add New" Foreground="Black" />
</ComboBox>
```

What can I do to get 1 or both of these items to display?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinRT/XAML (Windows 8)? If WinRT/XAML - are you targeting Windows 8 or Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Collection<T>.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for `List<T>`, which is used for ComboBox:

> Inserts an element into the Collection at the specified index.

Example:

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>();

// Add in begin of List
testList.Insert(0, "Choose Chore");

// Add in the end of List
testList.Insert(testList.Count, "Add New item");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting Windows 8.1 - the [`PlaceholderText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.placeholdertext.aspx) might be something you'd use for "Choose Chore" since that is not actionable UI and nothing should happen when you tap/click it unlike what happens when you tap a regular `ComboBoxItem`. As for the "Add New Item" thing - I'd recommend having a separate button to the side of the combo, but if you really have to - you could follow Anatoliy's suggestion and perhaps also use the `ItemTemplateSelector` to use a different `DataTemplate` for that item than for all the other items in the combo.